# FFMPEG codecpar struct always NULL and no AVStream codec parameters available

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, h.264

When I pass a file path into avformat_open_input  I can create a inputFormatContext, but none of the streams have any codec information associated with them, ie
inputFormatContext->streams[i]->codecpar is null.

```objectivec
    av_register_all(); //mandatory!
    AVFormatContext *inputFormatContext = NULL;
    int openInputValue = avformat_open_input(&inputFormatContext, [filePath UTF8String], NULL, NULL);
    if (openInputValue <0){
#ifdef DEBUG
        NSLog(@"[FFMPEG] handle error %s %d", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        char err[1024] = { 0 }; av_strerror(openInputValue, err, 1024);
        NSLog(@"[FFMPEG] error %d = %s", openInputValue, err);
#endif
        return nil; //error opening file
    }
```

I know that av_register_all() is deprecated, but otherwise
avformat_open_input doesn’t work.

```objectivec
    AVStream *inputVideoStream = nil;
    int inputVideoStreamIndex = 0;
    
    NSUInteger inputStreamCount = inputFormatContext->nb_streams;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < inputStreamCount; i++)
    {
        AVStream *inputStream = inputFormatContext->streams[i];
        if (inputStream->codecpar && inputStream->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
        {
            inputVideoStreamIndex = i;
            inputVideoStream = inputStream;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    
    if (!inputVideoStream) {
        avformat_close_input(&inputFormatContext);
        // handle error
        return nil;
    }
    
    if (avformat_find_stream_info(inputFormatContext, NULL) < 0)
.
.
.
```

How can I get the input video stream for frame reading later?

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version of FFmpeg.

Comment: @thekamilz I'm using the 4.3.1... I updated due to some other problems with older version (which was working)